# Access a single char at a time in 2D array

Tags: c

I am trying to check character-by-character so I need to get access to one character at a time in my 2D array. I tried to use double pointer (ex: `**p` ) but my program just crashes. So I use `*p` but it gives me rubbish.

Here is my code:

```
FILE *in;
in = fopen("thefiles.txt", "r");
if (!in) {
    printf("Failed to open input file\n");
    exit(1);
}

int j;
char phrase[N_STRINGS][MAX_LENGTH_OF_A_SINGLE_STRING]; 
char string[MAX_LENGTH_OF_A_SINGLE_STRING];

for( j = 0; j < N_STRINGS; j++ ) 
{
    fscanf( in, "%s", string );
    strcpy( phrase[j], string );
}

char *p;    
*p = phrase[0][0];
// Trying to use a pointer to point at the beginning(?) of the array

printf( "P = %s", p);
// After printing it out, I see that it gives me rubbish
```

Thanks much!

EDIT:

OK, I think I just solved my own problem. Ha!
All I needed was:

```
char p = phrase[0][0];
```

Shouldn't have messed with pointers in the first place :P

Comment: I don't see 'word' anywhere else in this code?

Comment: What is the variable 'word' ? Did you mean to use 'phrase' ? You didn't assign a value to 'p'.

Comment: Yes, sorry. Word should be Phrase. Let me edit it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that phrase is word , this is a sample program that should do what you want. If what you want is to just see the value of the first word stored in the file that is.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N_STRINGS   2
#define MAX_LENGTH_OF_A_SINGLE_STRING   1024
int main()
{
FILE *in;
in = fopen("thefiles.txt", "r");
if (!in) {
    printf("Failed to open input file\n");
    exit(1);
}

int j;
char phrase[N_STRINGS][MAX_LENGTH_OF_A_SINGLE_STRING];
char string[MAX_LENGTH_OF_A_SINGLE_STRING];

for( j = 0; j < N_STRINGS; j++ )
{
    fscanf( in, "%s", string );
    strcpy( phrase[j], string );
}

char *p = phrase[0];
printf( "P = %s", p);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: I get the whole phrase/word with the code you edited. I am trying to set a pointer at the first character(then move to the next char and so on) so I can do some comparisons. Thanks for the help!